# How to disable all Vim-LaTeX mappings?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I like some of the features provided by the Vim-LaTeX suite, but not all of them.

In particular, I dislike all of the mappings like `[[ = \left[ \right]` and the automatic placeholder stuff with `<++>`. I am a very fast typist but with that comes more typing mistakes, which I correct almost instantly by pressing backspace. Unfortunately, if something has automatically added a bunch of place-holders or expanded some expression, I then have to move around the document and remove more characters than necessary. For example, if I accidentally press `[` twice, instead of only having to delete one character, I have to delete 10.

Having already looked through the documentation, and some of the source, I have managed to disable some of these "features", but not all of them:

In particular:

```
let g:Tex_SmartKeyBS = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyQuote = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot = 0
```

(Turn off maps for backspace, double quote and triple dot.)

```
let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0
```

(Turn off `<++>` placeholder insertion.)

But I can't seem to find a way of turning off the other stuff. Anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**: I was able to "disable" some more things by setting:

```
let g:Tex_Leader = '`tex'
let g:Tex_Leader2 = ',tex'
```

(Which stops some expansions but still not all. It's not really disabling it but just making it less likely that you're going to type in `` `texa `` as opposed to the potentially more common `` `a ``, for example.)

PS: Personally, I think it is very poor practice to make an optional package that, when installed, greatly changes the default handling of your system. I don't mind some intelligent source highlighting etc, or some new commands (that don't clobber any old ones), but it seems unhelpful to enable this drastic kind of key remapping by default.

Comment: I got annoyed by that as well. Too much magic. In the end, I removed vim-latex and installed latex-box+snipMate instead. I have just been using this for a few days, but so far I am more than happy.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'm giving latex-box a shot now. Seems okay so far, with some nice completion features that don't get in the way.

Comment: Hey @Daniel -- I'm liking latex-box so far. One thing I changed though was the indenting code because that was a bit broken. In `ftplugin/latex-box/indent.vim`, change line 11 to this for much more sensible settings: `setlocal indentkeys=0=\\end,0=\\end{enumerate},0=\\end{itemize},0=\\item,0),0],0},o,O,0\\ `

Comment: Probably not what you want, but if you execute command `:set paste`, then all special mappings are disabled, and also the automatic indentation, etc. It is intended for use when you are pasting properly formatted code from elsewhere, but it can be also handy in other cases.

Comment: @JLDiaz Yeah, I often use `:set paste` for pasting code. I like automatic indenting, but yeah it's good to know that I can turn on paste if I'm entering text with strange side-effects (for example, after changing catcodes).

Comment: You are a really fast typist? Wow that's really cool.

Comment: Note that pressing `<Ctrl>-j` clears the `<++>` placeholder and goes into insert mode at that location, which allows you to just keep on typing. It's actually quite a useful feature. If I didn't know about this keybinding I also would have found it very annoying.

Answer (score 11):

Side note for anyone who ends up here looking for the same thing I am:

To disable specific `IMAP`s, add trivial `IMAP` commands to the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` (you may have to create it if it does not exist).  For instance,

```
" Undo some latex-suite macros
call IMAP('()', '()', 'tex')
call IMAP('{}', '{}', 'tex')
call IMAP('[]', '[]', 'tex')
call IMAP('::', '::', 'tex')
call IMAP('{{', '{{', 'tex')
call IMAP('((', '((', 'tex')
call IMAP('[[', '[[', 'tex')
call IMAP('$$', '$$', 'tex')
```

Answer (score 7):

I put `let g:Imap_FreezeImap=1` in my `.vimrc`. It should disable all of this annoying “magic”.

Comment: If that worked, it would be a great solution. Unfortunately, even if I add this, vim-latex still makes dozens of mappings (just check :map and :imap ). In fact, it even makes mappings when you're editing non-.tex files. But yes, this does certainly remove some of the more annoying maps. However, I'm pretty happy to use latex-box for the foreseeable future so I uninstalled vim-latex.

Comment: This is describe in `:help pausing-imaps`. It is a simple solution and seems to remove the most annoying things.

Answer (score 3):

The [Latex-Suite Reference](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/index.html) states in chapter [3 Latex-Suite Macros](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html) in section *Over-riding Latex-Suite Macros*:

> To delete a mapping, you can use
>   `call IUNMAP('FEM', 'tex')`
>   in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex_macros.vim.

**For example**

```
call IUNMAP('{}', 'tex')
```

will unmap expansion when typing `{}`.

---

<sup>The `IUNMAP` command was added Wed Dec 28 21:57:54 2016 +0100</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It should really not be the case, that the `tex` mappings are enabled for all files. So either you need to update your `vim-latex` or change a configuration option there.

I had the same problem with expansion like `[[ ~> \left[ <++> \right]<++>`. It always took to long to undo any errors, because normal undo will remove too much. So I found that you can insert *undo marks* with `^Gu` (literal `Ctrl-G u`) before the replacement. This way whenever I type `[[` by mistake or even want a literal `[[`, I just press the `<undo>` key and then only the `[[` is left.

See also my question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11625244/1534459), where I asked for the way to get the `<undo>` key in insert mode.

To automatically insert the undo mark, you need to change the `imap.vim` file of `vim-latex` and at the end of the `LookupCharacter` function, change the return line to

```
return a:char . "^Gu\<bs>" . bs . IMAP_PutTextWithMovement(rhs, phs, phe)
```

Notice that in order to write `^G` you have to type `Ctrl-V Ctrl-G`, only copy-paste will not suffice here.

I send this change as a suggestion to the `vim-latex` mailing list, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an active maintainer...