# Weird autocompletion in vim-latex

Tags: amsmath, vim

I am trying to write some inline equations in vim-latex, but when I type `\((` (To start an equation with a parenthesis), vim replaces it with `\\left(  \right)<++>`.

What is it doing, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Two backslashes before `left` or it's just a typo?

Comment: Two backslashes. It looks like it's changing the `((` to `\left( \right)<++>`, and leaving the original backslash alone.

Comment: Note that pressing `<Ctrl>-j` clears the `<++>` placeholder and goes into insert mode at that location, which allows you to just keep on typing. It's actually quite a useful feature. If I didn't know about this keybinding I also would have found it very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's standard vim-latex expansion for all brackets `((` will become `\left( <++> \right)<++>`, as well as `{{` will become `\left{ <++> \right}<++>`

See this answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158733/59716