# How to prevent vim-latex from making a placeholder on empty bracket pair?

Tags: vim-latex

Unlike the other questions I found so far, I am aware of the role of the placeholders and actively using the features of vim-latex. However I'm finding it hard to find help customizing them. One feature that gets in my way very often is the automated replacement of `{}` to `{}<++>` (and similarly for `()` etc.) with the cursor placed between the brackets. I often need to type an empty bracket pair for a macro and it is very distracting to remember to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> every time instead of writing in a linear fashion. I am sure I will never want to type `{}` to fill in the contents and jump out later, it's always a deliberate empty pair that's meant to stay empty.

How can I selectively disable this mapping? I have tried

```
call IMAP('{}', '{}', "tex")
```

but this, albeit solving the problem as stated, creates a new one by inducing an unwanted delay at typing the opening bracket, which is even worse.

Comment: Not sure, but can you not simply add `iunmap <buffer> {}` to your `after/ftplugin/tex.vim` ?

Comment: @marsupilam Thanks! I just tried and it leads to "No such mapping".

Comment: Right, that's because of the special `IMAP` function defined by the plugin (I don't know the first thing about vim-latex). Looking at the plugin's code in `vim-latex/plugin/imaps.vim`, I see there also is an `IUNMAP` function : 
`" IUNMAP: Removes a "fake" insert mode mapping.
function! IUNMAP(lhs, ft)`
**Conclusion** I would try `call IUNMAP('{}',"tex")` in the same `after` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely forgot that I left this question open. I found a complete solution in the meantime. The command `IUNMAP`, as suggested in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373561/how-to-prevent-vim-latex-from-making-a-placeholder-on-empty-bracket-pair/539379#comment923644_373561) by marsupilam, does what I want exactly, without the heavy implications of disabling more general blocks of features:

```
[~.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim]

...
call IUNMAP('{}', 'tex')
...
```

According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449307/16770), the command was still a rather recent addition to Latex-Suite at the time of posting my question and marsupilam's proposition did not work for me, which is why I did not close the question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your command prompt (:)

let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0

You can find more information in [this](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-place-holders.html)   link

You can put this in your .vimrc or .gvimrc file