# vim latex-suite, type ... instead of `\ldots`

Tags: vim-latex

Vim latex suite automatically turns ... into `\ldots` This is nice in text, but when writing tikz figures, one often needs to write the like of (MWE):

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%% THE TWO FOLLOWING LINES ARE THE IMPORTANT ONES %%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \x in {1, 2,...,10}
\draw (\x,0) -- (0,\x);
%%%%%%%%% END OF IMPORTANT LINES %%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

here the vim latex suite likes turning ... into `\ldots`

Is there any way to make vim ignore the three dots for a while?

Comment: Try `let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot = 0`

Comment: See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449307/150531), though this is not a temporary solution

Comment: thanks a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To (on a one-off basis) avoid triggering an IMAP entry using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (in insert mode) will insert the next character literally, as such <kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd> leaves `...` rather than triggering the `\ldots` replacement.

[This question elsewhere on the network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366869) discusses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in insert mode in slightly more detail.